# how to change click to mouseover or hover through jquery?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, tooltip

i want to display the date on mouseover or hover, right now it's onclick, i have used tooltip to display the data but i want to show the data on mouseover, i tried a lot but didn't get success? any body can help it will be appreciated, thanks in advance.

this is my code,  it want to change on clik to mouseiver/hover.

```
 <script>
 $(".ajax_link").click(function(e) {

e.preventDefault(); //Stops link from changing the page

var link = $(this).attr('href'); //Gets link url

$.ajax({ //Make the ajax request
  url: link,
  cache: false
}).done(function( html ) { //On complete run tooltip code

    //Display tooltip code goes here, returned text is variable html
    .done(function( html ) { 
        alert("text: " + html);
    });
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: Is there some reason you can't just use .mouseover() ?

Comment: just change .click to .hover

Comment: Have you tried use the `mouseenter()` `mouseleave()`?

Answer (score 3):

You can try changing this:

```
$(".ajax_link").click(function(e) {
```

to this:

```
$(document).on('hover mouseover mouseenter', ".ajax_link", function(e) {
     //e.preventDefault(); //<-------you can take this out no need for this
```

if you want to stop the jump of page then you can do this:

```
$(".ajax_link").click(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault(); // or return false;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use this.It will work for both events.

```
 $('#element').on('hover mouseover', function() {
        ...
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just:

```
 <script>
$(".ajax_link").mouseover(function(e) {

e.preventDefault(); //Stops link from changing the page

var link = $(this).attr('href'); //Gets link url

$.ajax({ //Make the ajax request
  url: link,
  cache: false
 }).done(function( html ) { //On complete run tooltip code

//Display tooltip code goes here, returned text is variable html
.done(function( html ) { 
    alert("text: " + html);
});
});
});
</script>
```

? Is there some reason you can't use .mouseover?

Answer (score 1):

use the [hover](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) function.

```
$('id').hover(function() {
  /* code for mouseover */
}, function() {
 /* code for mouseout */
});
```

Comment: You attempt to edit my answer because it's redundant ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15503535/how-can-i-select-one-object-per-each-related-object-in-django/15505469#15505469. If your edit is approved, that will return an object not a value. Please try it first before editing