# How can I select one object per each related object in django?

Tags: django, django-queryset

If I have two classes:

```
class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(...)

class Item(models.Model):
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group)
    published = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

How can I make a QuerySet to select the latest published Item from each Group? I guess it should be something like

```
Item.objects.order_by('published').distinct('group')
```

but I can't make it work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**models.py**

```
class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

    def latest_published(self):
        items = Item.objects.filter(group=self)[:1]
        for item in items:
            return item.published
        return ''

class Item(models.Model):
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group)
    published = models.DateTimeField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "{0}".format(self.published)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-published',)
```

**views.py**

```
def myview(request):
    groups = Group.objects.filter()

    [.........]
```

**template**

```
{% for group in groups %}
    {{group}} - {{group.latest_published}}<br/>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it. I thought Item.objects.filter(group=self)[:1] will return only one object?

Comment: @ersran9 From the question `How can I make a QuerySet to select the latest published Item from each Group?`. This query `Item.objects.filter(group=self)[:1]` return the latest published item (one item) in each group

Comment: Well, Isn't your code returning a single item too? since you `return` within the loop.

Comment: @ersran9 one item in each group, that's the requirements

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind loading ALL of the Item's into memory from the database, and you want to do it in a single query, then you can do this.  In my scenerio, there are about 8 "Items" and about 4 "Groups" so it's barely a performance hit to do this.

```
from itertools import groupby

items = [list(g)[0] for k, g in groupby(Item.objects.all().order_by('group', '-published'), lambda x: x.group_id)]
```

Add `.select_related('group')` to the inner queryset if you want to be able to access the group object.

**What is it doing?**

1. Queryset to get all items
2. Grouping the items by their group
3. Picking the first items from each group, and putting them into a list.